# MySQL: INSERT INTO table SHOW CREATE VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, show, information-schema

I need to write the column 'Create View' of SHOW CREATE VIEW in to a temporary table.

Note that i cannot use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA because the create view statement there is a little bit different to the statement i get from 'Create View'. Specifically the statement in INFORMATION_SCHEMA has the database schema name in the Create View statement and i want to dump this without the schema name. (I cannot use RegEx to remove the statement names because i cannot know if the schema name is set automatically or by the user how creates the statement)

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database specified in your connection by default differs from the database containing the view,  SHOW CREATE VIEW will return the same result as INFORMATION_SCHEMA. So you should not count on it. Try to unparse the text in your application, but it can be difficult to do.